# Count lines of text in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet of data for work that I need to split up in VBA.  A couple of columns have multiple lines of text and others do not.  I've figured out how to split the multiple lines of text, my problem is taking the column with a single line of text and copying it down.  For example:

```
Company_Name     Drug_1      Phase_2        USA
                 Drug_2      Discontinued 
                 Drug_3      Phase_1        Europe
                 Drug_4      Discontinued
```

Below is the code I am using to split columns B & C and then I can handle D manually, however I need column A to copy down into rows 2-4.  There's over 600 rows like this otherwise I would just do it manually.  (Note: I'm putting column B into A below, and column C into C)

```
Sub Splitter()
    Dim iPtr1 As Integer
    Dim iPtr2 As Integer
    Dim iBreak As Integer
    Dim myVar As Integer
    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim iRow As Integer

'column A loop
    iRow = 0
    For iPtr1 = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        strTemp = Cells(iPtr1, 1)
        iBreak = InStr(strTemp, vbLf)
        Range("C1").Value = iBreak
            Do Until iBreak = 0
            If Len(Trim(Left(strTemp, iBreak - 1))) > 0 Then
                iRow = iRow + 1
                Cells(iRow, 2) = Left(strTemp, iBreak - 1)
            End If
            strTemp = Mid(strTemp, iBreak + 1)
            iBreak = InStr(strTemp, vbLf)
        Loop
        If Len(Trim(strTemp)) > 0 Then
            iRow = iRow + 1
            Cells(iRow, 2) = strTemp
        End If
    Next iPtr1

'column C loop
    iRow = 0
    For iPtr2 = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        strTemp = Cells(iPtr2, 3)
        iBreak = InStr(strTemp, vbLf)
        Do Until iBreak = 0
            If Len(Trim(Left(strTemp, iBreak - 1))) > 0 Then
                iRow = iRow + 1
                Cells(iRow, 4) = Left(strTemp, iBreak - 1)
            End If
            strTemp = Mid(strTemp, iBreak + 1)
            iBreak = InStr(strTemp, vbLf)
        Loop
        If Len(Trim(strTemp)) > 0 Then
            iRow = iRow + 1
            Cells(iRow, 4) = strTemp
        End If
    Next iPtr2

End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, I obviously screwed up this post.  Sorry, I'll fix it when I get home

Comment: Please clarify your question and highlight the problematic part (are you just asking how to copy cell range in Excel VBA or else?). Regards,

Comment: It's not clear from your example where the cell boundaries are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bit of code I call the "waterfall fill" which does exactly this.  If you can build a range of cells to fill (i.e. set `rng_in`), it will do it.  It works on any number of columns which is a nice feature.  You can honestly feed it a range of `A:D` and it will polish off your blanks.

```
Sub FillValueDown()

    Dim rng_in As Range
    Set rng_in = Range("B:B")

    On Error Resume Next

        Dim rng_cell As Range
        For Each rng_cell In rng_in.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
            rng_cell = rng_cell.End(xlUp)
        Next rng_cell

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

**Before and after**, shows the code filling down.

[image]
[image]

**How it works**

This code works by getting a range of all the blank cells.  By default `SpecialCells` only looks into the `UsedRange` because of a [quirk with `xlCellTypeBlanks`](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/371987-problem-specialcells-xlcelltypeblanks.html#post1844081).  From there it sets the value of the blank cell equal to the closest cell on top of it using `End(xlUp)`.  The error handling is in place because `xlCellTypeBlanks` will return an error if nothing is found.  If you do the whole column with a blank row at top though (like the picture), the error will never get triggered.

Comment: That would work, except I can't figure out how to get the data in column B in your example to move down.  I've created a new question because I realized I did a poor job at asking this one.  Here is the url:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547953/vba-split-rows-that-have-multiline-text-and-single-line-text

Comment: I see from your new question what the problem is.  I'll add something over there.  A picture is worth a thousand words in this case.  This code is still relevant, you just have to split out the rows first.